# How to improve html form and styling?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am working on an HTML form for one of my courses and am hoping to get some advice on improving its styling. Specifically, I am struggling to get the radio button descriptors to line up with their respective buttons. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I am quite new to HTML so I apologize for any mistakes in the HTML/CSS.

[This is how my radio buttons currently appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KWUi.png)

**HTML:**

```
<h1> CONTACT FORM </h1>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="#" method="POST" class="form">
        <label for="name">FULL NAME</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="fullName" placeholder="Name" required />

        <label for="email">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email address" placeholder="Email" required />

        <label for="phone">PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. 012-345-6789" required />
        
         <label for="email">HOME ADDRESS</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address" required />
        
        <label for="message"> MESSAGE</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" cols="40" rows="10"> </textarea>

         
       
        <p class="contact_method"> PREFERRED METHOD OF CONTACT </p>
        
        
         <div class="buttonradio">
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="best_contact" value="HTML">
<label for="Phone">Phone</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="Email" name="best_contact" value="Email">
<label for="email">Email</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="text" name="best_contact" value="Text">
<label for="text">Text message</label>
        </div>
        
        
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
}
  
  
.form label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form input,
.form textarea {
  font-size: 12px;
  display:flex;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  outline: none;
   border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}


.form input:focus:required:invalid {
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/*   */


.form button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
}

/* send button styling */




button:hover {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  transition: background-color 2s; 
  /* change color on hover */
  
}
  
.buttonradio {
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
}
  
  .buttonst input{
   
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.contact_method {
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}



.container label {
    padding:5px;
    color:#222;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to group the label and radio inputs in a div or sum, then apply a display of flex, and align items of centre, all on the wrapper of the label and radio input.